# jQuery quicksand issue

Tags: jquery, plugins, filter, quicksand

So I am configuring the [quicksand plugin](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) on my new wordpress website to use it on my portfolio section.

I configured everything and it's working. You can see it live here:

http://www.tipoos.com/new/?page_id=43

**The problem:**

I have more jQuery scripts running on my site. For example, see the portfolio item thumbnails when hovering over the image. When I first run the page the hover images are working, but whenever I trigger the sorting quicksand functionality to filter my items the hover image effect on the thumbnails stop working and this is really annoying..

I figured maybe it has to do with a jQuery conflict or something, but whatever I tried didn't work -- couldn't find an answer anywhere...

Here is my JavaScript file, which contains all the scripts in the site including the quicksand settings: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4405634/functions.js

If anyone can assist I'd be happy.

Comment: close vote as off-topic. this is a jQuery issue, nothing to do with WordPress. look at replacing your event handlers with [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). your elements are being removed from/added to the DOM, so they're losing their event handlers.

Comment: @milo- It's about integrating quicksand into wordpress, what should I do then? post this question in the relevant stackexchange website?.

Comment: @songdogtech - I dont know how to accept answers, also I never received a straight good answer, I will look at the FAQ's - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has little to do with Wordpress and everything to do with jQuery. Forums and Q&A sites that deal with jQuery as a standalone library are better places to look.

You also need to learn how to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) or [Safari](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx) to see what JS and jQuery libraries are loading on your site and to resolve JS conflict errors.

You may also need to look at [Function Reference/wp enqueue script « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) on how to load JS within WordPress as you are learning jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @songdogtech, I actually know Jquery pretty good and everything seems to be working fine except for hover images with the quicksand but I will check again to see if there is a Jquery conflict or something. regardless - I am still looking to get some assistance here as I posted a link to my Javascript file. I hope that someone can check out my site and advice how to help.

Answer (score 0):

as I mentioned in my comment on your question, your issue is that the elements are cloned when animated, so they are losing the events bound to them.

[the solution is in their documentation](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/docs-and-demos.html#integration). I believe you can also solve it by binding your events via jQuery's [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which replaced the `live` method for binding events to objects which may exist in the future.

Comment: I managed to solve it somehow using a live function:



  `$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.items > ul > li').live('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).find('img.grey').stop(true, true).animate({'opacity': '0.2'}, {duration:500});
  
 });
 
 $('.items > ul > li').live('mouseleave', function(){
  $(this).find('img.grey').stop(true, true).animate({'opacity': '1'}, {duration:500});         
 });  
 
});`    in addition to my existing code. I hope it helps anyone who needs it